# Does it worth to use workflow engine for multi page forms

Tags: workflow-foundation

I need to build a multi page form for the company and we are not allowed to use out side form providers (so has to be built in house).

For a multi page form, I can simply save each page's info into a local database (or no sql) and load later.

But my colleague said we could try to use the workflow engine provided by azure to create save points and reload.

Is it right strategy to use workflow engine (it is an website product) or just use a normal database or nosql to store and reload?

Answer (score 0):

Workflow is a perfect solution for this scenario. The thing you should think about is whether you want to offload the workflow instance to a database or memory.